# PHP: use value from an array in an if statement within a function

Tags: php, arrays, function, if-statement

I have the following code which works fine inline with my code:

```
    if ($progressData[1] == "yes") {

        echo "Complete";
    }
    else

        echo "Not Yet Complete";
```

However, I would like to call it from a function:

```
function progressOutput () {

    if ($progressData[1] == "yes") {

        echo "Complete";
    }
    else

        echo "Not Yet Complete";

}
```

When I call `progressOutput()`, I get "Not Yet Complete", even though `$progressData[1]` is equal to "yes".

Here is how I am calling the function:

```
Mission Status: <?php progressOutput(); ?>
```

What do I need to do to get `progressOutput()` to return "Complete" when `$progressData[1]` is in fact equal to "yes"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to pass the variable from the calling scope into the function in order for the function to have access to it.

Your function should accept an argument:

```
function progressOutput ($progressData) {
    if ($progressData[1] == "yes")
        echo "Complete";
    else
        echo "Not Yet Complete";
}
```

And when you call it, you should provide an argument:

```
Mission Status: <?php progressOutput($progressData); ?>
```

It's typically a bad idea for your functions to output data directly; you could clean it up by returning a value instead of echoing it:

```
function progressOutput ($progressData) {
    if ($progressData[1] == "yes")
        return "Complete";
    return "Not Yet Complete";
}
```

And outputting the value returned by the function:

```
Mission Status: <?= progressOutput($progressData); ?>
```

Comment: Thanks meagar! This did the trick! I had tried the first part, but forgot to also provide the argument when I called the function. Thanks again!

Answer (score 2):

Look up [variable scoping](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php) in PHP. PHP's variables do not "trickle" down to lower scopes and must be declared explicitly global in the lower scopes to become visible.

```
function progressOutput() {
   global $progressData;
   etc...
}
```

The other option is to pass in progressData as a parameter:

```
progressOutput($data);

function progressOutput($progressData) {
    ....
}
```

Comment: Thanks Marc B. Your second option worked. I haven't tried the first one, but I'm sure that would work as well. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

The $progressData is not in the scope of your function
You should pass it to your function.

function progressOutput ($progressData){
// it will be available here now
}

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using the function as shown above, this means that within the function this variable is not known.

In order to to that you could at `global` to the variable like this:

```
global $progressData;
```

after that you could use it.

Or you should pass the variable in the function:

```
progressOutput(progressData[1]);
```